# How do I transclude Special:WantedPages as a numbered list?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I’ve found that I can transclude Special:WantedPages using double-curly-braces (`{{Special:WantedPages}}`), but the result is an in-line comma-separated list, not a vertical numbered list like you see on the page itself. I figured out that I can specify how many pages to list with a slash (`{{Special:WantedPages/6}}`)... is there another parameter that would let me specify the list format?

I tried manually reformatting it using StringFunctions (`{{#replace:{{Special:WantedPages}}|,|<br>}}`), but this just produced an empty string. Why doesn’t that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no parameter to output what you want, the format is hardcoded.

`{{#replace:{{Special:WantedPages}}|,|<br>}}` does not work because the value of the first argument (infact all of them) is not parsed, neither designed to be. So what the function actually sees is the string '{{Special:WantedPages}}' which of course, does not contain any comma; ergo there's nothing to replace.

Comment: Note I have opened issue on Wikimedia bug tracker to allow the numbered list output https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T341015, which clearly looks better